# Saving pandas Dataframe to xlsb format in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, xlsb

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. The Date column is of type Object.
df :
DATE
0   2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z
1   2021-08-01T00:00:00.000Z
2   2021-06-01T00:00:00.000Z
3   2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z
4   2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

I am trying to convert the dataframe into xlsb format so that I can use this excel for further analysis.

> Why I need to convert it to xlsb format?
>
> I tried removing the TZ component and convert the column into YMD
> format by following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744589/how-can-i-convert-the-string-2020-01-06t000000-000z-to-datetime-in-python). The issue I am facing is
> even after converting, the date column still has timezone component.
> And when I am performing imputation and outlier treatment in R, it is
> unable to fetch the year,month,day fields.
>
> Therefore, I am trying to convert the dataframe into xlsb format and
> then import it, so that the timezone component doesn't occur and I am
> able to proceed with my imputation/outlier treatment.
>
> If someone has better ways to remove the timezone component from the
> columns or any other method to transform the datecolumn into YMD format is most welcome.

I have tried searching in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061445/how-to-write-pandas-dataframe-into-xlsb-file-in-python-pandas). But couldn't find the correct answer.

Comment: Why do you specifically need xlsb, and not xlsx, for example?

Comment: @BigBen, I want to perform time series imputation/outlier treatment in R, and before that I am performing some feature engineering in python. But the issue is even if I remove the 'T...Z' component using `d=datetime.fromisoformat(dt[:-1])` and then  `d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` still the date column has timezone component. And someone asked me to convert and save my dataframe in xlsb and then import it to resolve the date time issue.

Comment: @BigBen I have edited my question for better understanding.